# ClickOnce Deployment - Run at Startup

Tags: .net, clickonce

I've successfully configured my clickonce deployed application to run on system startup by adding a registry key to: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\.

However, when the system starts my app runs before networking is available.  Is there anyway for me to configure this so that my app waits for networking resources to become available?  Or will I need to check for networking on launch?

Thanks,
Parv

Comment: Why are you using ClickOnce then?  Why not a more typical WinForm app with an update component (ala NLaunch)?

Answer (score 3):

I post this anticipating a flurry of downvotes, but even if it is an ugly solution, it should work.

It's not the most elegant approach, but rather than using the registry, you could put a shortcut into the user's startup folder on their programs menu.  It should load after the network is available.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try to update manually after launch. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx