# visual studio right click problem, i can not find view option

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In a lot of forums i read:

> If you right click on your install
>   project, View -> Registry, you can add
>   a registry key to the list. The key
>   has properties (right click ->
>   Properties) AlwaysCreate, and
>   DeleteAtUninstall, which should
>   perform what you need, based on the
>   stuff in the other post about the
>   Registry table. Don't add a value to
>   the key, set AlwaysCreate to false,
>   and DeleteAtUninstall to true

where in visual studio 2008 i can found view->registry. I right click on my windows application but there is no view option...

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [add a deployment (install) project to your solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyh6k4k4%28VS.80%29.aspx). Then you can access the [Registry Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4dsy50b%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [other deployment options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yb26w40%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) by right-clicking on the setup project.

Comment: hmm thx for your answer. But i have deploy by "click once". is there any of this possibility for "DeleteAtUninstall"?

Comment: There's a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763611/set-registry-key-through-clickonce-installation which may help