# download click once application from browser

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

i was working on win application made its setup, and put it on site. when some user comes to site for first time it pormpts user to download my application. and while running setup i created a key in registry, that was checked in my script by site, that if key exists than user will not be prompted as he/she has installed app. when user uninstalls application, setup will delete regisrty key, wirtten on installation time.

Note: i added my site to trusted site and chaged its security to read my script.

Now scenario changes, user has asked to implement app in clickonce, so that they had to update app instead of uninstall and reinstall it. they still want clickonce app setup on site as mentioned above, but problem here is that when i run app first time it will write registry for that application but on uninstall it will not delete registry. as it is mentioned in following link [set registry key through click once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763611/set-registry-key-through-clickonce-installation).

is there any way to accomplish this requiremnent. any help will b appreciated

Comment: You don't need to uninstall and re-install the application to get it updated. Once the application has been installed you can just update the relevant exe's or assemblies.

Comment: thanks for response. i meant to say that if user has uninstalled application, for any reason. than i want to prompt him again to reinstall, but as clickonce uninstall do not delete registry values, so what should i do that browser me prompt user again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a registry key before the application uninstalls you will need to launch the uninstall process from a location within your code that you can control.  To do this, you will need to have the user launch the uninstall process from within your application.  When the user starts the uninstallation process, you will need to remove the registry key from within your application before continuing the uninstallation.

There is an excellent blog post ([found here](http://www.jamesharte.com/blog/?p=11)) by Jim Harte regarding automating the uninstall/reinstall process.  His article is in regards to an issue with certificate renewal, but the uninstall process is the same.

If your user uninstalls the application through the Add/Remove Programs dialog, the key will not be removed.  There is unfortunately no way that I am aware of to halt the uninstall process of a ClickOnce application so that you can remove a registry key.  It's just an annoyance that you will have to live with, unless someone else around here has found a "creative" solution.

Answer (score 2):

check the update option is enable in the Publish settings ( if needed specify the minimum version for updating specify it also) .
when the application starts it will automatically checks for update. user dont need to uninstall every time

Comment: thanks for response. i meant to say that if user has uninstalled application, for any reason. than i want to prompt him again to reinstall, but as clickonce uninstall do not delete registry values, so what should i do that browser me prompt user again.