# ClickOnce: Insert value on widows register on instalation and remove it on uninstalling

Tags: .net, clickonce, regedit

I have developed a desktop application and a dll-wrapper.

Now, i want to distribute the wrapper to some external developers. These developers are going to include the DLL in some of their projects and applications, and are going to call some functions. However, for a comercial reason, I only want to allow them calling some functions if they have installed my desktop application. So, the Wrapper checks that exist some values on windows registry, and if not throws an exception. I have developed this requisite with no problem.

However, I need help with the desktop application. ¿How can I insert an entry on windows registry on the ClickOnce installation, and how can i remove it on when my desktop application is uninstalled?.

If is not  posible to insert a custom entry on the ClickOnce installation process, Is there any workaround to accomplish the commercial requisite?

I know that ClickOnce inserts some entries under: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

But I want to insert some custom entries.

UPDATE:

I have taken a look to this similiar question [Set registry key through ClickOnce installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763611/set-registry-key-through-clickonce-installation)

On that question, an user asks how to run a clickonce application on startup. He asks how to insert a key on [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run].  But I DON'T need to write a key on a SPECIFIC entry.

ClickOnce already inserts key on windows' register, so it has permisions to do it. It inserts keys under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall by his own. I only need to set another key on the same entry that it is already inserting. But I can't figure out how configure it.

Comment: @FrankJ please check the update

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that ClickOnce can't be configured to write to the registry other than what it does by itself. You have to look into other deployment products if you want to customize it in the way described. You can add another application that does that for you as described in [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6bbe17a9-2356-4745-a56f-5edbaa5abf4e/can-i-write-a-clickonce-setupexe-that-modifies-the-registry?forum=winformssetup) but that seems very hackish.